# Error: IPv6 address must be 16 bytes

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I need to Jekyll to be installed to my computer, by:

```
gem install jekyll
```

with or without `--verbose`, I get this:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (ArgumentError)
    IPv6 address must be 16 bytes
```

I don't know anything about ruby, please help. thanks.

I use Ubuntu 14.04, and there is no IPv6 on my connection information.

ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

gem 2.2.2

Comment: Can you send the result of a `gem install jekyll --verbose`

Comment: @DavidJacquel same output

Comment: @egig what is your version of ruby? you can get this info with `ruby --version` I believe. Or `ruby -v`.

Comment: @matrixanomaly is right edit your question and give us more informations about your environment. Os and ruby version are important.

Comment: See https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/1274

Answer (score 0):

A very bad workaround, but it works:

```
sed -i 's/host = uri.host/host = "http:\/\/rubygems.org"/g' /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.2/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb
```

Note: pay attention to the ruby path.